# Cannot load database configuration: Is a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I bought a course on udemy and the first thing in the course is to open a server with the command `rails server` the server starts successfully:

```
PS C:\curso ruby\ruby curso udemy\projeto_udemybasico> rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.8 application starting in development       
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!      
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 3.1.4-p223), codename: Llamas in Pajamas     
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

However, if I access this localhost:3000 in the browser I see a lot of error lines and the VS Code terminal also has these same errors:

```
Puma caught this error: Cannot load database configuration:
Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/curso ruby/ruby curso udemy/projeto_udemybasico/config/database.yml (Errno::EISDIR)
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:39:in `read'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:39:in `read'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:14:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:18:in `new'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb:18:in `parse'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:334:in `database_configuration'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:266:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `class_eval'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:95:in `block in execute_hook'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:85:in `with_execution_control'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:90:in `execute_hook'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:76:in `block in run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `each'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:75:in `run_load_hooks'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:333:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.11/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `run'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:29:in `before'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `block in make_lambda'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:687:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in `catch'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in `block in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block in halting'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `block in invoke_before'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `each'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `invoke_before'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:129:in `run'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:125:in `run!'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:78:in `block in run!'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:75:in `run!'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:138:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

In the course, the teacher shows a screen like "Hi, we're on Rails" and mine has this bunch of errors, can anyone help me?

- My operating system is Windows.
- Ruby Version: 3.1.4
- Rails version: 7.0.8

I want to be able to access the server success screen to continue classes and test the settings of my projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From rails [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database):

> Just about every Rails application will interact with a database. You can connect to the database by setting an environment variable `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` or by using a configuration file called `config/database.yml`.
>
> Using the `config/database.yml` file you can specify all the information needed to access your database

So `config/database.yml` must be the **file**, **not folder** like in your case

You need to delete this folder first, create (if not exists) this file and fill it like in the link above

If it is completely new application and file is absent, it will be faster to create new app again

You can find basic templates in the [rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/databases), choose needed depending on your RDBMS